# CuPy - Does multiple functions result in multiple kernels?

Tags: python, cuda, gpgpu, cupy

I recently made a `CuPy` version of my `numpy` code and I only get an improvement factor of x5-x15. When I check my GPU usage, it seems low (<1%). I want to optimize the way my code operates to get faster results.

Generally, I want to make multiple successive `CuPy` operations on a `cupy. ndarray`.
For example, generating a random vector:

```
def randomUniformUnitary(N):
    theta = cp.random.rand(N) * 2 * cp.pi
    phi = cp.random.rand(N) * cp.pi
    x = cp.sin(phi) * cp.cos(theta)
    y = cp.sin(phi) * cp.sin(theta)
    z = cp.cos(phi)
    output = cp.stack((x, y, z), axis=-1)
    return output
```

I have multiple questions that [the docs](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/overview.html) didn't seem to answer. (They do say on-the-fly kernel creation, but no explanations)

1. Kernel merging?

Does CuPy creates a kernel for `rand()` then sends back the data and creates a kernel for the multiplication of the `2`, then... Or will all these calculations combine into one faster kernel?

2. Kernel combinaison criteria?

If it is the case, what are the criteria that lead to such behavior? One-line operations? Same `array` operation? Function operations? Is it okay performance-wise to `def` separate function with only one `cupy` operation on an array, or is it better to double write the code at some places and get all the cupy functions into a single Python function?

1. Own kernels?

If each calculation is done separately and there is no "kernel merging", then I feel I should probably make my own kernels to optimize? Is it the only way to achieve GPU optimization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Generally speaking, cupy does not create a single kernel encompassing the behavior of separate program statements.  There is no automatic fusion.  cupy has a [fuse function](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/reference/generated/cupy.fuse.html) which applies to user-defined kernels (see below)
2. See item 1
3. Yes, you can create your own kernels.  cupy provides a variety of methods for you to create [user-defined kernels](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/tutorial/kernel.html#), and this is another possible method for combining multiple operations into a single underlying kernel call.

You should be able to further characterize the above statements/behavior with a GPU profiler (or with inspection, since cupy is open source).

Comment: That did answer most of my questions, thank you for the time. Are we usually right if we say that user-defined kernels will be faster if multiple operations are incorporated into one since there would less data sharing between CPU and GPU?

Comment: I think that might be a common observation.  However cupy understands that you don't want to move data unnecessarily between CPU and GPU, and a typical sequence of cupy statements won't do that.  cupy is designed to intentionally keep the data on the GPU until a specific need for it arises on the CPU (e.g. via a `.asnumpy` statement).   The benefit from kernel fusion ("multiple operations are incorporated into one") doesn't depend on eliminating unnecessary CPU/GPU traffic, but is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53305830/), generically. It saves memory bandwidth.